# Como Selecionar Elemento Anterior CSS ? A href id

Tags: html, css

Existe alguma maneira de selecionar o elemento anterior de outro elemento com CSS?

Eu preciso ocultar só o primeiro elemento `<ul></ul>` cujo tem dentro um `<a href = "#TAB-1"` .

Fiz dessa maneira abaixo e não funcionou:

```
<style>

ul.tabs:has(> a[href="#tab-1"]) 
{ 
    display: none !important;
}

</style>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab-1" class="active">TAB1</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab-2" class="active">TAB2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pode usar o seletor **:nth-child(3)**. No caso ficaria

```
ul:nth-child(1){
...
}
```

Mas não funciona para o elemento anterior no html, apenas para os elementos selecionados.

pode dar uma olhada na documentação da monzilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: deu certo, tive que especificar a classe:
ul.tabs:nth-child(1){
display: none !important;
}